# How do I incorporate an existing SharePoint Online site into Microsoft Teams?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

I have become a fan of Microsoft Teams but I have an existing SharePoint Online site called "Site" with a document library URL of https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Site/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx. Other folks in the organization are already using that Site. I'd like to layer a new Microsoft Teams site on top of this existing SharePoint structure so that the new Teams Files tab that gets generated will lead to that old Site's existing document library. However, when I create a Teams site with my Site name, the Files tab leads to a new SharePoint Site47 URL (note the new numerical suffix), i.e., https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Site47/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx. The SharePoint back end is therefore separate and distinct from my existing one. Any way to converge my new Teams Site without having to delete my existing SharePoint "Site" and start over? I understand that had I started the site in Teams instead, I wouldn't have this problem but I'd rather not have to start everything from scratch if possible.

Comment: It would be fantastic if this worked, but it doesn't seem to. When I create a Team from an existing Office365 Group as directed, it does not link to the document library in the original SharePoint for the Group. The new Team has an empty General tab. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the site already have a Group? If not, do that first. To do this step, there should be a link on the settings menu with the text "connect to new office 365 group. Full instructions are [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-connect-to-office365-group).

If the Site is already connected to a Group, then when you create the Team, on the screen where it asks for a Team name, leave that blank and instead click the link at the bottom that says "create a team from an existing Office 365 group".

Comment: I never saw the "Connect to new Office365 Group" menu item. That was probably because my site was already on the Modern UI, so I already had an Office 365 group. That took care of your first paragraph. Followed your second paragraph and voila! My new Teams site connects with my existing SharePoint site! Thanks a lot, pal.

Comment: I don't understand....I'm trying the same routine today on a different SharePoint site so that I can create a Teams wrapper around it, and I can't get past the screen that asks for a Team name because it won't let me leave it blank!

Comment: I just tested it again to make sure there isn't a new bug, and it's working fine for me. You're clicking the "create a team from an existing office 365 group" link?

Comment: I just don't get that link in the drop-down menu for the site's gear button.

Comment: If I go to https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/groups, I can see the group that was created for my previous site with which I had success. The new site I'm trying to replicate this solution for isn't listed as a group here. I can "Add a group", but I just don't know if just giving it the same name as the site will be enough to cause the same effect as clicking on the link you say (which I happen to be missing!) If I create a group with the same name as the SharePoint site, will that group be automatically "connected" to my SharePoint site?

Comment: Create the team from the teams app, or teams.microsoft.com, not the gear icon, and not the admin center.

Comment: Right, I tried that but I can't leave the Team name blank. It won't let me now. So I figured maybe the site does not have an Office365 group. That's where I'm stuck, i.e., in determining that.

Comment: if you create a new group, it will not be connected to the existing site. If you created a new "modern" communication site, it doesn't get a group, and this isn't an option. The "Connect to new Office365 Group" option should appear on classic team sites.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82884/discussion-between-shieldofsalvation-and-mike2500).